# Error when saving entities using breezejs(missing ScriptAssemblyAttribute )

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, breeze, script#

I get the following error when clicking on the save button in the **breezejs** nuget sample:

**Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'**

I get the error when **SaveChanges** in the code below is called:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
   return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

Actually **ScriptAssemblyAttribute** does not exist in the intellisense when I lookup **System.Runtime.CompilerServices** in the code editor and I'm targeting .NET 4.5.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the latest .NET 4.5 (not RC2)? My brief search of the web indicates that this kind of error occurs on machines that aren't on RTM. (See https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/3)

Comment: I have .NET 4.5(v4.5.50709) which came with the final release of VS2012. So it is RTM. I'm also referencing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Script# has something to do with it. I uninstalled it and the error was gone.

Comment: You should not reference a script# assembly in a non-script# project. The solution is likely as simple as that...